# How can I link 2 .exe in c++?

Tags: linker

I mean to link them and transfer some attribute.
for example first program send array and second program get , then send another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you are looking for is probably IPC: Inter Process Communication.

There are tons of ways to do this. If you need your two programs to talk together (not just one direction), you might want find it easiest to use some sort of networking library.

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors. If this is just quick and dirty, you could look into memory mapped files (but this might be POSIX only).

Comment: This chapter from The Art Of Unix Programming might be of interest: http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch07s02.html (Taxonomy of Unix IPC Methods)

Comment: You're welcome, Amin. BTW: Read the whole book when you get time. It is really worth it!